# How to modify parser_rules in wysihtml5?

Tags: wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I need to modify the parser rules for my img element.

Currently it only support very limited attributes with limit data types as following:

```
           "img": {
                "check_attributes": {
                    "width": "numbers",
                    "src": "url",
                    "height": "numbers",
                    "data-sda": "url"
                }
            }
```

How to make it support more elements like class or id.

In my solution I, the user, drag images and drop it inside the editor which is wysihtml5 as I said before.

Answer (score 0):

This pull request on github adds what seems like exactly the feature you're looking for: [extend checkAttributes value type](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/pull/258). It's a small change; you could do it by hand on your own copy without any fuss.